# c# web mvc deploying to IIS10

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I'm trying to publish my first C#/ASP.NET Web MVC project. The server on which it has to be deployed is a Microsoft Server 2016, with IIS 10 installed. In the interface of Visual Studio has a feature where you can one-click-publish, using "Web Deploy". Web Deploying requires five fields to be entered. "Server", "Site name", "User name", "Password", and "Destination URL". What do each of these fields mean? I assume the "Server" is the ftp address of my server? And then username and password the ftp login data? But what are "Site name" and "Destination URL"?

Answer (score 0):

Your server must support Web Deploy. this is different from ftp publishing. You'll find you answers here

https://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx